# How to keep cursor on row when data is updated?

Tags: java, vaadin, single-page-application

The data in SPA should be updated periodically to show the current db state in the table. I'm trying to do it by the click event on a table row.

```
table.addListener(
    new Table.ValueChangeListener() {
        public void valueChange(final ValueChangeEvent event) {

            BeanItemContainer<Incoming> bic;
            Query query = sess.createQuery("...");
            List l = query ...
            bic = new BeanItemContainer<Incoming>(l);
            table.setContainerDataSource(bic);
        }
    }
);
```

But at this line the cursor is lost:

```
table.setContainerDataSource(bic);
```

How can I keep cursor on row when data is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current approach, I would do :

```
...
Object selection = table.getValue();
bic = new BeanItemContainer<Incoming>(l);
table.setContainerDataSource(bic);
table.setValue(selection);
...
```